# GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check issue

Tags: java, ldap, kerberos, gssapi

I am facing a strange problem with Kerberos/Ldap authentication using GSSAPI. 
I have a simple java class that does authenticate to Kerberos then do an Ldap search.

This program does fail on some of our KDC/AD controllers with this exception:

```html
No encryption was performed by peer.
[stderr] javax.naming.AuthenticationException: GSSAPI [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Final handshake failed [Caused by GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)]]
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(LdapSasl.java:150)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2694)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:293)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
[stderr]  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
[stderr]  at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
[stderr]  at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
[stderr]  at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
[stderr]  at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:82)
[stderr]  at com.ricoh.test.LdapGSSApiTest.search(LdapGSSApiTest.java:199)
[stderr]  at com.ricoh.test.JndiAction.run(LdapGSSApiTest.java:440)
[stderr]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[stderr]  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:337)
[stderr]  at com.ricoh.test.LdapGSSApiTest.search_gssapi(LdapGSSApiTest.java:189)
[stderr]  at com.ricoh.test.LdapGSSApiTest.runTest(LdapGSSApiTest.java:111)
[stderr]  at com.ricoh.test.ButtonTest$1.actionPerformed(ButtonTest.java:123)
[stderr]  at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.panel.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
[stderr]  at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.panel.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
[stderr]  at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.panel.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
[stderr]  at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.panel.Component$MultiEventHandlerImpl.exec(Unknown Source)
[stderr]  at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.core.manager.EventRunner$Dispatcher.processEvent(Unknown Source)
[stderr]  at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.core.manager.EventRunner$Dispatcher.run(Unknown Source)
[stderr] Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Final handshake failed [Caused by GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)]
[stderr]  at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.doFinalHandshake(GssKrb5Client.java:310)
[stderr]  at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:169)
[stderr]  at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(LdapSasl.java:114)
[stderr]  ... 25 more
[stderr] Caused by: GSSException: Token had invalid integrity check (Mechanism level: Corrupt checksum in Wrap token)
[stderr]  at sun.security.jgss.krb5.WrapToken_v2.getDataFromBuffer(WrapToken_v2.java:257)
[stderr]  at sun.security.jgss.krb5.WrapToken_v2.getData(WrapToken_v2.java:189)
[stderr]  at sun.security.jgss.krb5.WrapToken_v2.getData(WrapToken_v2.java:164)
[stderr]  at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.unwrap(Krb5Context.java:946)
[stderr]  at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.unwrap(GSSContextImpl.java:384)
[stderr]  at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.doFinalHandshake(GssKrb5Client.java:216)
[stderr]  ... 27 more
```

I am running Java 1.6 and disabling RC4 encryption type one the server.

Anyone got an idea what could be the reason for this? Any known issue with the JVM?

NB: I am able to run the program properly on some of our KDC and do the ldap search properly.

Update: My program works just fine using JDK-8 so I am guessing it's a Java 1.6 related issue.

Comment: Google that error message. And you will discover that a possible cause for this kind of errors is that **the Sun/Oracle JVM does not support AES128 nor AES256 by default**. Even though the US export policy for encyption tech has changed years ago, duh. You must download the "unlimited strength encyption" signed JARs separately. OpenJDK is another story, though.

Comment: Thank you Samson, I am aware of that... I installed the unlimited strength encryption jars and are installed properly. But, interestingly that my program works on JDK 1.8 and fails on Java 1.6. and it looks like a JVM 1.6 issue..

Comment: Indeed, there have been, and will be, issues - cf. the final phrase in https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html

Comment: Get commercial support from Oracle for Java 1.6 or migrate off.